# Why is the location not being fetch in my production server?

Tags: django, gunicorn

I'm geolocating users using the following snippet of code in my view:

```
try:
  jsonResponse = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip="+request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']).read()
  response = simplejson.loads(jsonResponse)
  kwargs['loc'] = response['geoplugin_countryCode']
except:
  kwargs['loc'] = 'error'
return basic_html(request,'index.html',kwargs)
```

In my dev server (`manage.py runserver`) this works fine. In my `gunicorn` production server, `loc` is blank (not even `error`). What's going on?

Comment: Have you confirmed that you have a value for `REMOTE_ADDR`? Often it isn't populated, so it might be that you're sending a blank IP and  geoplugin service is returning a blank country code in response.

Comment: @Dan Yeah, nginx was forwarding the real IP, but in a different header. Sorted it now. Post this as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you confirmed that you have a value for `REMOTE_ADDR`? Often it isn't populated, so it might be that you're sending a blank IP and geoplugin service is returning a blank country code in response.